# Native Quarkus appears to be ignoring lines of code that contain objects from classes configured for reflection

Tags: quarkus, graalvm, graalvm-native-image, quarkus-native

In my quarkus project, I depend on a third-party project. When I run the application in dev mode or generate a jar file, everything goes fine. But not in Native mode.

When I generate the native, this error happens:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create instance of class com.x.x.x.x.Issue. Registering an InstanceCreator or a TypeAdapter for this type, or adding a no-args constructor may fix this problem.

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create instance of class com.x.x.x.x.issue.Issue. Registering an InstanceCreator or a TypeAdapter for this type, or adding a no-args constructor may fix this problem.
       
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Type com.x.x.x.x.Issue is instantiated reflectively but was never registered. Register the type by adding "unsafeAllocated" for the type in reflect-config.json.
       at org.graalvm.nativeimage.builder/com.oracle.svm.core.graal.snippets.SubstrateAllocationSnippets.instanceHubErrorStub(SubstrateAllocationSnippets.java:315)
       at jdk.unsupported@21.0.1/sun.misc.Unsafe.allocateInstance(Unsafe.java:884)
```

I created the following file for reflection configuration and the error during compilation was resolved:

```
[
  {
    "name": "com.x.x.x.x.Issue",
    "allDeclaredConstructors": true,
    "allPublicConstructors": true,
    "allDeclaredMethods": true,
    "allPublicMethods": true,
    "allDeclaredFields": true,
    "allPublicFields": true,
    "unsafeAllocated": true
  }
]
```

But when I run the application natively, it doesn't seem to be performing any action on the Issue class objects. Only `Log.info("STARTED ACCEPT")` and `Log.info("STARTED ACCEPT")` are written to the log file, other lines seem to be ignored, nothing happens, not even an error.

```
public void accept(final ScheduledExecution scheduledExecution) {
            Log.info("STARTED ACCEPT");
            final List<Issue> issues = retrieveIssues();
            Log.info("ISSUES :" + issues);
            Log.info("FIRST ISSUE Key: " + issues.get(0).getKey());
            Log.info("FINISHED ACCEPT");
}
```

When I run it in development mode or run the jar, all logs are written or printed correctly.
Does anyone have any idea what could be happening?

Comment: Not sure about the second part of your question, but you can use `@RegisterForReflection` for third-party classes, see https://quarkus.io/guides/writing-native-applications-tips#registering-for-reflection

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that this is what's happening, but could it be that Native Image doesn't see and include some code. Can you try [running with the tracing agent](https://www.graalvm.org/latest/reference-manual/native-image/metadata/AutomaticMetadataCollection/), making sure that the config produced by the agent is picked up, and see if that fixes the issue?